# Font size different in different browser for same font family

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am using Open Sans font family but when I open my webpage in different browser the font size looks different in different browsers. In Internet Explorer the font size look bigger then Firefox.

I use font finder in Firefox Firefox and show correct font size and family but in actual the font size is looking small and its also effecting the div sizes in different browsers.

In Internet Explorer the div size is bigger then Firefox.

I did not understand the problem and thanks for help in advance.

Comment: what is your CSS to set the font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two browsers use two different font types. They may never be exactly the same but if a browser doesnt support a file type it defaults to something else which could be causing the discrepancy. Below i have listed the file types for each browser. You may want to use a service like font squirrel to create the other types. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

TTF - Works in most browsers except IE and iPhone.
EOT - IE only. 
WOFF - Compressed, emerging standard. 
SVG - iPhone/iPad.

Comment: But are you using the EOT file for IE? You should try to upload your font into http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ webkit generator. This is a great tool and they will make sure your fonts are the right type. They also provide you with the css you need to include your fonts. You can also try to base 64 encode your font (which font squirrel also does). Web fonts are tricky and you can run across problems with cross domain hosting if they are not produced correctly. read this blog from Paul Irish which explains it pretty well.

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by units used(in this case i suspect `em`). Check your css for your 'suspicious' divs and see if they have dimensions based on font-size(em)

Comment: overgeneralization. it could be because different browsers have different "default font sizes" and they arent setting one for the `html`, it could be because he is using webfonts and the browser-specific font engines are causing wildly different renderings ... answering without specific information is pure speculation.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea It's a starting point. I could say your answer is a overgeneralization too. How is my answer an overgeneralization regarding div size in corelation with font-size?

Comment: "its caused by" = definitive statement, followed by "i suspect". Rushing to judgment on one specific cause that may not be the cause may only prolong the search for the true answer. And you could say my answer is an overgeneralization? By "answer" you can only either mean "comment on your answer" or "question", because I wouldn't presume to know the answer without first understanding the details of the problem.

Comment: Ok, let's not pollute the post, and wait him to see the result.